# apt-get install [any package] has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, packages

I'm having trouble installing any package on my Raspberry Pi v1 B. Whenever I run `apt-get install [any package here]`, it always failed with `E: [package name] has no installation candidate`. I don't understand why this is so, as it was working some time ago.

My APT sources.list

```
deb http://repozytorium.mati75.eu/raspbian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

My APT sources.list.d:

`raspi.list`:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie non-free contrib rpi
```

`jenkins.list`:

`deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/`

`apt-get update` output:

```
Get:1 http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports InRelease [6,842 B]
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/main armhf Packages [111 kB]
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Sources
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Sources
Get:3 http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/contrib armhf Packages [20 B]
Get:4 http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/non-free armhf Packages [14.1 kB]
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ InRelease
Hit http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Release.gpg
Hit http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Release
Hit http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Packages
Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Translation-en_GB
Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Translation-en
Ign http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://repozytorium.mati75.eu jessie-backports/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Fetched 132 kB in 17s (7,731 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: I have taken care of the `hxxp` problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by editing the `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie non-free contrib rpi` to `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main non-free contrib rpi`

Answer (score -1):

try running "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade"

This may solve your problem.

Comment: Ran it already, did not work.